# Dynatree maximum levels

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

Is it possible to define maximum level of nodes in Dynatree? Or, how to define maximum depth of nodes in a tree?

Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to define that at the outset.

You could use `node.getLevel()` to check a predetermined maximum level.  If you reach the maximum value do not allow new subnodes to be created off that node.